# How can I GET a json of all the projects I have access to using Gitlab API?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I want to get a json file with all the projects that appear on my [Dashboard](https://gitlab.com/dashboard/projects) and that I have **developer access** to. I though it would be a very simple job using the [Gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html), more specifically  the [projects API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html), but so far, I can't. Is it possible?

Note : I generated a token with **api scope**.

Here's what I tried and the results :

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXX" https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects`

It gives me all the projects I don't own but I have master access to. It doesn't include the ones I have developer/other access to. The result is the closest to what I'm looking for so far.

---

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXX" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects`

It gives me a list of projects I seem to have access to, even though I have no idea what they are.

---

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXX" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/myUser/projects`

It gives me all the projects I own. I thought that one would work since the documentation says *Get a list of visible projects for the given user.* I also tried with the *membership* attribute set to true or false, but there is no difference.

Any advice/help would be appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any straightforward way.

The closest thing I can think of is to view all projects within a given namespace, but that doesn't completely give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question, but maybe other will stumble over this as I just did.

My solution was adding the per_page option

curl -s -X GET -H 'Private-Token: ' 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?per_page=100'